# How to add custom local JS files in Gatsby correctly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, gatsby

I´m a newbie on react and gatsby but i´m working on a little project as practice anda I have a little problem. I want to add a custom JS file to the project (little functions for a calculator on the index). I used Helmet to import them and on develop enviroment is working fine, but once build, is not.

```html
import Helmet from "react-helmet"
import { withPrefix, Link } from "gatsby"

export default function homePage() {
  return (
    <main>
      <Helmet>
        <script src={withPrefix('/functions.js')} type="text/javascript" />
        <script src={withPrefix('/escritura.js')} type="text/javascript" />
      </Helmet>
}
```

I´m not sure what I am doing wrong. Someone can help me, please?  You can see the project proof version live here:

https://modest-hoover-aac2d1.netlify.app/

In the final version, every input should be filled automatically, but is not happening.

Comment: Read [how to host static files in Gatsby](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/how-to/images-and-media/static-folder/). Also, think critically about why you need to host these as external Javascript rather than just importing them as a part of your Gatsby project.

Answer (score 0):

[`withPrefix`](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/how-to/previews-deploys-hosting/path-prefix/#add-the-path-prefix-to-paths-using-withprefix) is a helper function that only works in build mode because in development mode paths don't need to be prefixed:

> For pathnames you construct manually, there’s a helper function,
> `withPrefix` that prepends your path prefix in production (but doesn’t
> during development where paths don’t need to be prefixed).

So if your code works well under development mode, just remove `withPrefix` and leave your code as:

```
export default function homePage() {
  return (
    <main>
      <Helmet>
        <script src={`/functions.js`} type="text/javascript" />
        <script src={`/escritura.js`} type="text/javascript" />
      </Helmet>
}
```